# How do orders work in the iFruit App for Los Santos Customs?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online, grand-theft-auto-ifruit

I have just ordered my first upgrades via the iFruit App to my **online** car.

Roughly how long does this take to apply to my in-game content?

Do I have to take money out of my bank to pay for this or will it be auto-withdrawn?

Do these items automatically apply to my car or do I need to take the car to Los Santos Customs?  (or do I need to reload?)

It said that the order has been sent, but is there any record of this order in my iFruit App?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deduction of money is automatic, you don't have to do anything in game.

Once the order is sent, it will take a few minutes to get a notification in game, it really depends on the status of the Rockstar Servers.

If you're game is on, and you're playing while submitting an order, you'll have to visit a Los Santos shop to receive the order.

If you're offline when submitting the order, starting up the game and going online should get the most recent order automatically. No extra work needed.

There isn't a way of seeing a record of orders in the iFruit App, the best record are the texts you receive on the character in game, though they don't contain much detail.

Comment: Take the car to the shop to check.

Answer (score 1):

The iFruit App is no longer supported by Rockstar Games and was removed from app stores on Dec. 12, 2022.

<sup>- Rockstar Games Support article: [Grand Theft Auto: iFruit App Shutdown](https://support.rockstargames.com/articles/11966031291027/Grand-Theft-Auto-iFruit-App-Shutdown)</sup>

Rockstar Games released the [**GTA Online License Plate Creator**](https://www.rockstargames.com/gta-online/license-plates) website on Apr. 20, 2023. It's a replacement for the iFruit App's license plate creator. You can access it here: https://www.rockstargames.com/gta-online/license-plates.

> Roughly how long does this take to apply to my in-game content?

In my experience, within a few seconds of placing your order, you'll get an in-game text message letting you know that it's ready to be picked up at Los Santos Customs. ([Rockstar Support mentions that it could take a few minutes.](https://support.rockstargames.com/articles/15666547278355/Grand-Theft-Auto-Online-License-span-class-highlight-Plate-span-Creator-FAQ))

> Do I have to take money out of my bank to pay for this or will it be auto-withdrawn?

I believe it will be auto-withdrawn.

> Do these items automatically apply to my car or do I need to take the car to Los Santos Customs? (or do I need to reload?)

You need to take the car to any location that can customize your vehicle, e.g., [mod shops/garages](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Mod_Garages#Grand_Theft_Auto_V_and_Grand_Theft_Auto_Online) like [Los Santos Customs](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Los_Santos_Customs#LSC_in_GTA_Online) or any other [vehicle workshop](https://gtamag.com/en/gta-online/garages). Once inside the mod shop, select "Process App Order" to install the custom license plate to your vehicle.

Custom license plates initially cost 600 GTA$ to install on the vehicle you selected on the License Plate Creator website. After that, you can install the same custom license plate on any other vehicle for free.

Heads up: There is a bug in the game (as of Apr. 24, 2023) that causes [colored headlights](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Los_Santos_Customs/Lights#Headlights) to [revert to stock lights after installing a custom license plate](https://www.reddit.com/r/gtaonline/comments/12u9cwu/colored_headlights_become_stock_after_custom/). Until this bug is fixed, you will need to pay again to have your colored headlights back.

> It said that the order has been sent, but is there any record of this order in my iFruit App?

The status of your order and all custom license plates you created are listed on the License Plate Creator website.

<sup>Source and more info at the Rockstar Games Support article: [Grand Theft Auto Online License Plate Creator FAQ](https://support.rockstargames.com/articles/15666547278355/Grand-Theft-Auto-Online-License-span-class-highlight-Plate-span-Creator-FAQ).</sup>